# Getting Invalid input whenever inputting anything into a input function

Tags: python

okay, I was trying to build a guess the number game that can use the only two languages that I know of: English and Chinese, but currently, my code is a bit broken right now. I have no clue why and how it's broken, but I just need some help. Did I type a wrong parenteseise? did I misuse a function?

```py
"""
Guess The Number
Write a program where the computer randomly generates a number between 0 and 20.
The user needs to guess what the number is.
If the user guesses wrong, tell them their guess is either too high, or too low.
This will get you started with the random library if you haven't already used it.
"""

def ENGLISH_hello():
    print("Hi, welcome to guess the number, here, you will guess a number from 1 to 100")
def CHINESE_hello():
    print("你好，欢迎你到猜数字， 在这里，你护额才一个数字从1到100")
def chinese_guess():
    print('ALL IS WELL')
def english_guess():
    print('ALL IS WELL')
def guess_the_number():
    try:
        Language = input("Hi, if you are fluent in english, type 'E'. 你好，如果你会说中文，请打 'Z'")
        if Language.strip == "z" or Language.strip == "Z":
            chinese_guess()
        elif Language.strip == "e" or Language.strip == "E":
            english_guess()
        else:
            print("INVALID INPUT")
            guess_the_number()

    except Exception as E:
        print("Sorry, something went wrong: " + str(E))

guess_the_number()
```

Comment: `.strip` is a method, so you should call it as `.strip()`! You can also use `.lower()` or `.upper()` to do your comparison only once, or perhaps `.startswith(("z", Z"))`, which will accept a tuple

Comment: anyways, I'm a beginner, I found this and decided to make a game.

Comment: Excellent, and welcome to a great programming language!

Comment: thx @ti7 now, I might publish the code on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [String.strip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) is a function
So it should be used as Language.strip()

Comment: Thank You! your answer is very helpful!